# Losing NSURL property after viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsurl

I'm want detect link clicks in a UIWebView which is inside one of my ViewControllers and then initiate a new ViewController which is basically another UIWebView with the detected link.

heres my code:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

    NSURL *url = [request URL];

    if (self.interceptLinks){

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        BrowserViewController *browser = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"browserViewController"];
        NSLog(@"sending url== %@", url);
        [browser openBrowserWithUrl:url];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"browserDetail" sender:self];

        return NO;
    }
    else {

        self.interceptLinks = TRUE;
        return YES;

    }
```

}

Then in BrowserViewController.h

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *incomingURL;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *browserView;
 - (void)openBrowserWithUrl:(NSURL *)url;
```

Then in BrowserViewController.m

```
- (void)openBrowserWithUrl:(NSURL *)url
{
    self.incomingURL = url;
    NSLog(@"incomming_URL==%@", self.incomingURL);
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad_url == %@", self.incomingURL);


    self.browserView.delegate = self;
    self.browserView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    [self.browserView loadRequest:[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:self.incomingURL]];





[self.view addSubview:_browserView];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
```

}

The NSLog inside the "openBrowserWithUrl" returns the desired NSURL, but the one inside "viewDidLoad" returns null, what am I doing wrong here ??

Comment: which method viewDidLoad() or openInBrowser() executes earlier? this is an answer

Comment: I believe it's a bit wrong to load request in viewDidLoad()... You have method openBrowserWithURL() and this method should be responsible for loading request, you issue may gone in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` will actually instantiate a new instance of `BrowserViewController`. I'm not familiar enough with storyboards to know how to do this, but there is a `UIViewController` callback that will let you know when a segue is being performed, so that you can pass it the `incomingURL`.

If you want to perform it manually, instead of using storyboards, you can replace your `performSegue` call with

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:browser animated:YES];
```

Comment: You might want to look into `prepareForSegue:sender:`

Comment: Oh I did not know performSegueWithIdentifier created a new instance of the viewController, thanks so much Guy now it works =)